# ViewModel's LiveData value is not being updated with two-way data binding

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-livedata, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel

I'm studying the components of Android Jetpack and I tried to replicate a similar app with [this](https://github.com/android/sunflower)

In my ViewModel have a query to a Room database that returns a LiveData object

```
class EditWeekViewModel internal constructor(
    private val weekRepository: WeekRepository,
    private val id: Int
) : ViewModel() {
    var week: LiveData<Week> = weekRepository.getWeek(id)
}
```

I declared my ViewModel variable inside the layout

```
<data>
    <import type="com.pascaciorc.turniptracker.data.Week" />
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.pascaciorc.turniptracker.viewmodels.EditWeekViewModel" />
</data>
```

This EditText is supposed to do the two-way data binding

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@={viewModel.week.date}"/>
```

But I can't seem to make the two-way binding work

Is there something wrong about the LiveData object?

This is my dao

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM week where id = :id")
fun getWeek(id: Int): LiveData<Week>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `MutableLiveData` and not `LiveData`. `LiveData` is read-only and you cannot edit an object of `LiveData` type.

Comment: I tried changing the repository return value to MutableLiveData but I get the next error  
`error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData<com.pascaciorc.turniptracker.data.Week>).
    public abstract androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData<com.pascaciorc.turniptracker.data.Week> getWeek(int id);`

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at this [codelab for ViewModel](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-view-model/#0) or this [one for Room](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin/#0). Google recommends to use the backing properties such as

```kotlin
private val _week = MutableLiveData<Week>()
val week: LiveData<Week>
    get() = _week
```

and then in XML you can use

```xml
android:text="@{viewModel.week.date}"
```